# iPhone SDK 3.0 Targetting 2.2.1 SDK

Tags: iphone

Just got the latest beta for iPhone SDK up.  This is the update for the upcoming 3.0 release of the iPhone SDK.  Unfortunately, I'm not getting a bunch of errors for targetting the 3.0 platform.  This is nice to know for me to mark future work, but I need to get some other stuff done first.  Unfortunately, the "target" field no longer shows me the 2.2.1 SDK, and defaults to 3.0, resulting in a myriad of errors that I'd like to fix later.

What actions should I follow to fix this?  I've already tried changing the default base SDK in the properties for the project to no avail.  Does installing 3.0 basically remove the 2.2.1 SDK?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  The error I was getting occurs for a beta build so this probably shouldn't be a persistent solution, but if anyone else is having trouble with trying to use the latest beta of XCode+iPhone0S3 installation, you will find that you can only target the 3.0 OS after you select it in the Overview dropdown.  Even if you were targetting a different active SDK previously, they will all be gone as soon as you select the 3.0 target.

The way to fix this problem is to just delete all the user-specific project files and to reopen the project.  Before that, make sure the base SDK is 2.2.1, etc.

This is a lot easier than downloading the 2GB stable XCode just to target the previous SDK.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Which are the user-specific project files? What does "before that, make sure the base SDK is 2.2.1" mean? You mean in "Project | Edit Project Settings | Build | Architectures | Base SDK"? Will 2.x be available in that drop down?

Comment: That's right.  The base SDK is 2.2.1 is when you go to edit project settings.  2.x WILL appear in the drop down in that section.  It just won't be in the Overview section.

User-specific project files are any files that isn't code, and isn't your the xcodeproj file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the info - I see it for "Device" but what about the iPhone Simulator? Is there any way to get that to show up? Thanks again.